# Removing a column in java from a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a java method that will take a 2d array and add the contents to an new 2d array expect for a specified row.  So if I have the 2d array

```
1234
1234
1234
```

and I want to remove the 3rd column, I would like to get

```
124
124
124
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to get this to work.  The best I can come up with is the following method.

```
private static int[][] removeCol(int [][] array, int colRemove)
{
    int row = array.length;
    int col = array[0].length;

    int [][] newArray = new int[row][col];

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if(j != colRemove)
            {
                newArray[i][j] = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return newEx;
}
```

Right now this method will return this

```
1204
1204
1204
```

but it would work much better if I could get my desired results.  Is there a way to do this or am I stuck with my current results?

Comment: Hint: (a) The new array has to have fewer columns - one less than the original. (b) Each of the columns that follow the column to be removed is supposed to be at an index *one less* than it used to be. So if you remove column 3, the what was in column 4 is now at column 3, what was in column 5 is now at column 4, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one variable `currColumn` which indicates the position of current column and the resultant array will have one less column than the original. So According to this you can change your code.

```
private static int[][] removeCol(int [][] array, int colRemove)
{
    int row = array.length;
    int col = array[0].length;

    int [][] newArray = new int[row][col-1]; //new Array will have one column less


    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0,currColumn=0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if(j != colRemove)
            {
                newArray[i][currColumn++] = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return newEx;
}
```

Another better approach is to use a Dynamic Structure like [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). So here you need to have Array of ArrayList and then you can remove the element with [remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) method. In case if you want to update any element then you can use [set()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)) method.

Answer (score 0):

Just use another index that doesn't automatically increment on loop run:

```
private static int[][] removeCol(int [][] array, int colRemove)
 {
int row = array.length;
int col = array[0].length-1;
int oldCol = array[0].length;

int [][] newArray = new int[row][col];

for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0, k=0; j < oldCol && k < col; j++)
    {
        if(j != colRemove)
        {
            newArray[i][k++] = array[i][j];
        }
    }
}

return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By keeping your logic with 0-based column number :

```
    private static int[][] removeCol(int[][] array, int colRemove) {
    int row = array.length;
    int col = array[0].length;

    int[][] newArray = new int[row][col - 1]; // You will have one column less

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        if (j != colRemove) {
          newArray[i][j > colRemove ? j -1 : j] = array[i][j]; // If you're looking at an index greater than the one to remove, you have to reduce index by one
        }
      }
    }

    return newArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In second iteration check the colRemove value and move +1 for other iteration. See the code below

```
private static int[][] removeCol(int [][] array, int colRemove)
{
    int row = array.length;
    int col = array[0].length-1;

    int [][] newArray = new int[row][col];

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if(j>=colRemove){
                 newArray[i][j] = array[i][j+1];
            }
            else{
                newArray[i][j] = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you replace the elements to remove by the default value of `int`, that is : `0`.

If it is not the element to remove you copy the element :

```
if(j != colRemove)
{
     newArray[i][j] = array[i][j];
}
```

Otherwise you do nothing (so it takes the default `0` value from `int`).

You should rather reduce from 1 the second dimension of the new created array.

You could follow this way :

- Use a global loop to iterate on the row (first dimension of the array)
- Use two sequential inner loops to iterate on the column (second dimension of the array). 
  The first one iterates until "the column to remove - 1" and makes a simple copy of the element in the new array.
  The second starts from "the column to remove" and shifts to left each element of the original array in the new array.

Here is a working code :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Array2D {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] arrayOriginal = new int[][]{{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}};
        int[][] arrayNew = removeCol(arrayOriginal, 2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayNew));;
    }
    private static int[][] removeCol(int [][] array, int colRemove)
    {
        int row = array.length;
        int col = array[0].length;

        int [][] newArray = new int[row][col-1];

        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < colRemove; j++)
            {              
                newArray[i][j] = array[i][j];                
            }

            for(int j = colRemove; j < col-1; j++)
            {                          
               newArray[i][j] = array[i][j+1];
            }

        }

        return newArray;
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
[[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is not as efficient as it could, but I does work:

```
public String[][] colDel(String[][] array, int deletedCol) {
    if (deletedCol > array[0].length - 1) {
        return null;
    }
    var result = new String[array.length][];
    int n = 0;
    ArrayList<String> tmp;
    for (var row : array) {
        tmp = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(row));
        tmp.remove(deletedCol);
        result[n++] = tmp.toArray(String[]::new);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Briefly, an instance of ArrayList is created for each row. Then the n-th column is removed, as indicated by the second parameter. Finally the arraylist is transformed back into an instance of String[], and the resulting String[][] is returned.

Cheers,

Coti

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String[][] dropColumnFromTable(String[][] table, int colNumber) {
    int rows = table.length;
    int col = table[0].length - 1;
    String[][] result = new String[rows][col];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col+1; j++) {
            if (j < colNumber) {
                result[i][j] = table[i][j];
            } else if (j == colNumber) {
                // Do nothing
            } else if (j > colNumber) {
                result[i][j-1] = table[i][j ];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should explain why this code answers the question. Just dumping lines of code maybe is not very helpful. You can still edit the answer and add explanation.